# On the rings $R$ with the property that $eR \cong fR$ for all primitive idempotents $e, f \in R$

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-rings

Let $R$ be a (commutative or non-commutative) ring with identity. As usual, an idempotent $e \in R$ is *primitive* if $eR$ (the principal right ideal generated by $e$) is indecomposable as a right module over $R$; equivalently, $e \ne 0_R$ and $e \ne f+g$ for all non-zero orthogonal idempotents $f, g \in R$.

> **Question.** Is there a standard name and/or a "non-trivial characterization" for the rings $R$ with the property that, whenever $e$ and $f$ are primitive idempotents, then the right $R$-modules $eR$ and $fR$ are isomorphic?

The condition is equivalent to requiring that any two indecomposable direct summands of the regular right module $R_R$ are isomorphic.

For instance, every von Neumann regular ring satisfying the *comparability axiom* (as per the unnumbered definition on p. 80 of Goodearl's book on von Neumann regular rings) fulfills the above condition: In particular, this is the case with any prime, von Neumann regular, right self-injective ring (loc. cit., Corollary 9.16).

Comment: For an Artinian ring this is the same as being a matrix algebra over a local ring. I guess this should also be true for a semiperfect  ring